# Sorting by objectId() in mongoDB using Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What is the proper way in Mongo to sort by objectId() using Doctrine?

Example Mongo data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505105d62c6f14f9316d77c2"),
    "ISBN" : "9780805075120"
}
```

Query:

```
    return $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->sort('_id', 'asc')
        ->limit(250)
        ->getQuery();
}
```

Comment: At a glance this should work and I'd say it is a proper way. Maybe the only thing I'd change is `_id` to be name of field of mapped identifier but both approaches should work as ODM is leaving fields unknown to mapping intact

Comment: You are right, the issue I was having involved a paginator conflicting with the limit. Thanks!